# Powershell System.Xml.XmlElement but I use System.Xml.XmlDocument?

Tags: xml, powershell

I keep getting the following exception in my PowerShell script:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] does not
>   contain a method named CreateElement'.

But as far as I know I am using `System.Xml.XmlDocument`?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6(v=vs.110).aspx

What am I doing wrong?

```
$file = "file.xml"
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $file)

if ($xmlDoc) {
    $xmlDoc.layout.nodes.SetAttribute("environment", "develop"); #this works

    $newNode = $xmlDoc.layout.nodes.CreateElement("Node")
    $newNode.SetAttribute("name", "Hello world")

    $xmlDoc.AppendChild($newNode)

    $xmlDoc.Save($systemConfigFile)
}
```

The XML file is before I launch this script:

```
<layout>
    <nodes enviroment="[uknown]">
    </nodes>
</layout>
```

I expect the outcome te become:

```
<layout>
    <nodes enviroment="develop">
        <node name="Hello world" />
    </nodes>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you show (editing your question) a sample of the original XML and the result you're expecting? Have you tried with `.CreateNode` instead of `.CreateElement`?

Comment: I updated it for you. I just tried the .CreateNode but I got the same exception on that one. I also can't find CreateNode in the documentation.

Comment: And what is the original structure before setting attributes and new node?

Comment: I eddited the question for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at this line:

```
$xmlDoc.layout.nodes.CreateElement("Node")
```

This is calling the method `CreateElement(...)` on the object `$xmlDoc.layout.nodes`. We could break it into two lines like this:

```
$something = $xmlDoc.layout.nodes
$something.CreateElement("Node")
```

We know that `$xmlDoc` is a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` object, but what type of object is `$something`? It doesn't refer to the whole document, it refers to the `<nodes>` element. From the error message, we learn that it is in fact a `System.Xml.XmlElement` object.

A few lines down, you make the opposite error: you call `AppendChild` on `$xmldoc`, when actually you want to append it *to the specific element*.

So, first we need to use `$xmlDoc` to *create* the new element; then we can use `$xmlDoc.layout.nodes` (which I called earlier `$something`) to say where we want to put the new element:

```
$newNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Node")
$newNode.SetAttribute("name", "Hello world")

$xmlDoc.layout.nodes.AppendChild($newNode)
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a new node you have to declare a new node in the XML layout with `CreateNode()` and append this node to the parent node like this :

```
$file = "file.xml"
[xml]$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $file)

if ($xmlDoc) {
    $xmlDoc.layout.nodes.SetAttribute("environment", "develop")

    #part that adds new node
    $secNode = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element","node",$null)
    $secNode.SetAttribute("Name","Hello world") | Out-Null
    $xmlDoc.layout.nodes.AppendChild($secNode) | Out-Null
}

$xmlDoc.Save($file)
```

**Returns :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
  <nodes environment="develop">
    <node Name="Hello World" />
  </nodes>
</layout>
```